# Should I have a heroku worker dyno for poll a AWS SQS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Im confusing about where should I have a script polling an Aws Sqs inside a Rails application.

If I use a thread inside the web app probably it will use cpu cycles to listen this queue forever and then affecting performance.

And if I reserve a single heroku worker dyno it costs $34.50 per month. It makes sense to pay this price for it for a single queue poll? Or it's not the case to use a worker for it?

The script code:

> **What it does**: Listen to converted pdfs. Gets the responde and creates the object into a postgres database.

```
  queue = AWS::SQS::Queue.new(SQSADDR['my_queue'])    
  queue.poll do |msg|
     ...
     id = received_message['document_id']
     @document = Document.find(id)
     @document.converted_at = Time.now
     ...
  end
```

I need help!! Thanks

Comment: I suppose my answer would depend on what you're doing with the queue. How important is it to you that messages get processed in a timely fashion? What processing do you perform once you've received a message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three basic options:

1. Do background work as part of a worker dyno. This is the easiest, most straightforward option because it's the thing that's most appropriate. Your web processes handle incoming HTTP requests, and your worker process handles the SQS messages. Done.
2. Do background work as part of your web dyno. This might mean spinning up another thread (and dealing with the issues that can cause in Rails), or it might mean `fork`ing a subprocess to do background processing. Whatever happens, bear in mind the 512 MB limit of RAM consumed by a dyno, and since I'm assuming you have only one web dyno, be aware that [dyno idling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-idling) means your app likely isn't running 24x7. Also, this option smells bad because it's generally against the spirit of the [12-factor app](http://www.12factor.net/).
3. Do background work as one-off processes. Make e.g. a `rake handle_sqs` task that processes the queue and exits once it's empty. [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) is ideal: have it run once every 20 minutes or something. You'll pay for the one-off dyno for as long as it runs, but since that's only a few seconds if the queue is empty, it costs less than an always-on worker. Alternately, your web app could use the Heroku API to launch a one-off process, programmatically running the equivalent `heroku run rake handle_sqs`.

Comment: Nice answer! The first option seems the right one, but for me is a little expensive paying for it. The third option I have tried once without Scheduler, but the the one-off process stay alive for 1 minute and its gone.

Comment: Again, thanks for the answer. One last doubt: If I wonder to listen to multiple queues, I can put it inside a single worker right?

Comment: Sure. `ReceiveMessage` can only receive from one queue, of course, but if you're single-threaded and selected the drain-the-queue-and-exit strategy, there's nothing to stop you from processing multiple queues sequentially.

Comment: Didn't quite understood the strategy. Did you mean switching between what queue it will be pooling?

Comment: Option 3 is where you run a one-off process that runs `ReceiveMessage` and subsequent processing in a loop that stops when the queue is empty. If you put code to handle each queue in a separate Rake task, you could say `rake handle_queue1 handle_queue2 handle_queue3` and completely process three separate queues in one invocation.

Comment: Thanks man! For now I will run 3 processes as one-off. Later I will be  thinking in workers as you advice me. Hope that this one-off processes doesn't appear expensive in the heroku's bill.

Comment: Heroku pro-rates by the second, so if you run a total of 1% of the time, it'll be < $4/mo. Also, the free dyno-hours allotment is slightly greater than the number of hours in each month, so it might end up being free anyway.

Comment: Actually the each process will be up to 24h per day, but it doenst mean that I'm processing something, but I guess it still counts. I'm afraid